# No audio through either soundbar or desktop on Debian

Tags: debian, audio, kde, alsa

I'm using a Debian stable box with a Dell monitor and the [Dell AX510](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&cs=19&sku=313-6412) "stereo soundbar". The "soundbar" has a large frontal speaker as well as two headphone jacks on the left.

While the hardware itself is operational (I can hear static when I crank up the volume), I cannot make it produce any sound. I'm running KDE and have filled up the `master` bar through `alsamixer`.

The desktop itself also has a headphone jack on the desktop itself. I really do not mind using either the soundbar **or** that particular headphone jack; I'm just looking to have some sound output through either source. I'm going to be using headphones anyway since this is a work computer.

Audio-related `lspci` output:

```
jason@debian:~$ lspci | grep Audio                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

And some machine specs:

```
jason@debian:~$ uname -r
3.16.0-4-amd64                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
jason@debian:~$ cat /etc/debian_version                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
8.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have tagged your question with `alsa` and you have used `alsamixer`, so my question may sound silly, but are you sure you are not running `pulseaudio`?

Try `ps aux | grep pulse`. If you see a line with `pulseaudio --start`, then `pulseaudio` is running. In this case `pavucontrol` should allow you to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I checked the process log and, indeed, pulseaudio was running. I installed `pavucontrol` and opened up a YouTube video to produce some sound. I'm seeing the sound meter in the "Output Devices" tab of `pavucontrol` going up and down, indicating non-zero volume, yet I still have no sound through any one of my options.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a BIOS issue. Don't want to pollute the knowledge base with irrelevant details, but pulseaudio or alsa had nothing to do with it. Thank you all for your time.